# MySQL Query Distinct in Paris PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, idiorm

I have a requirement to use Paris/idiorm PHP for building my queries. I tried many possibilities and yet couldn't find a solution. I am new to PHP and SQL and don't know much about ORM. I just thought someone would help me out in building the query to get distinct names of the last updated timestamp.

```
-----------------------------------------
id  |   name       |    timestamp
-----------------------------------------
1   |   testuser   |  2012-11-19 17:02:48
2   |   testuser   |  2012-11-28 11:15:46
3   |   testuser   |  2012-11-19 11:02:49
4   |   testadmin  |  2012-11-28 10:50:05
5   |   testadmin  |  2012-11-28 11:15:46
-----------------------------------------
```

I did  the following query and was able to get the names and their first timestamp but couldn't get the latest timestamp

```
    $output = ORM::for_table('sample')
                ->raw_query('SELECT id,name,timestamp FROM sample GROUP BY name',array())
                ->find_many();
```

hope there's some solution to this.

Comment: sorry about the typo in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the latest timestamp for each name in a subquery then join it back against itself. try,

```
SELECT a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT name, MAX(timestamp) maxStamp
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY name
        ) b ON a.name = b.name AND
                a.timestamp = b.maxStamp
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2e4b/1)

Comment: the testuser's time_stamp is not the latest one. it shows same timestamp as the testadmins in sqlfiddle

Comment: yeah noted but is there any better way to do this ?? because I use paris php to build queries for me. I executed the raw query above and it takes a bit more time to provide me results. ?

Comment: do you have properly define an index in your table?

Comment: yeah have a primary_index as id.

Comment: works exactly like how I anticipated it to work thanks a lot KJ.

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = ORM::for_table('sample')
  ->distinct()
  ->raw_query('SELECT id,name,timestamp FROM sample GROUP BY name',array())
  ->find_many();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $output = ORM::for_table('sample')
                ->raw_query('SELECT DISTINCT(name),id,timestamp FROM sample ORDER BY id DESC',array())
                ->find_many();
```

hope this helps

i try to ordered it DESC to you will get the last or latest log of the user